# how to map some string(s) into another and print output in perl

Tags: regex, perl, mapping, nhibernate-mapping

I have a log file and a table name entered by user as input. Now this table name entered by user will be searched in log file and if any data corresponding to that table is found it should be mapped into a more non technical language which the end user can understand.

Can anyonyone suggest how to do this mapping and then print the equivalent mapped string as output.

For example the data to be mapped is:

```
!!!!!! Diff004: record 0 differs in content for fields 'pid'
!!!!!! Diff005: record 1 differs in content for fields 'pid'
!!!!!! Diff006: record 2 differs in content for fields 'pid'
```

This data to be mapped into more non-technical statement and then those mapped statemennt to be shown to user instead of these.

real data on request of @TLP

```
Checking table CTusr000...
!!!!!! Diff004: record 0 differs in content for fields 'pid'
!!!!!!                        
uexpday,uexphr,uexpmin,uexpsec
db1 [Rec 000000] 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,00 00,53 55 50 45 52 55 53 45 52 00 00,77
```

Comment: What do you mean with `should be mapped into a more non-technical language`?

Comment: Like replacing this text with something more easy to understand fir a non techie person

Comment: @ashish Word of advice: Any non-tech person who cannot understand these very simple sentences is someone you don't want as an employee. And do you really need Perl code to dumb down this text? You should probably give an example of what you mean.

Comment: @TLP my question is about mapping the data. it's just an example I wrote nothing else. I f you want to see some real string I have edited my post just take a look

Comment: Actually, you haven't edited your post.

Comment: @TLP plz checkout now

Comment: @TLP it's about migrating to a new release these logs are some of the changes indicated.

Comment: And what do you want that changed into? I mean, I have no idea what you mean by "non-technical". Is "field" a technical word? At some point you have to draw the line, or it becomes illegible.

Comment: @TLP ok the above given example(after modification) shows a change in a particular record in database after migrating it to a newer version. So let's say I want to put this same line in front of other people (working on same release) as an explaination when he/she search for the status of particular table (i.e. "Record number xyz differs in so and so manner"). How should I do that? thats my question.

Comment: @FilippoLauria please look at the comments and modified post. I hope you might be able to help out.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard for me to figure out what *mapped into a more non-technical language* means, since that's not technical language, but it is.. *english*.

So, have a look at the following example that shows you how to get `record no` and `field name`, from a generic `$line`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "!!!!!! Diff004: record 0 differs in content for fields 'pid'";

$line =~ /^!{6}\s+.*record\s+(\d+)\s+differs.*fields\s+'(\w+)'$/;

print "record no: $1\n";
print "field name: $2\n";
```

Combine those informations in the better *non-technical* manner you intent.

The example is for a single `$line` only.
I'm leaving to you reading lines from file task and iterative processing task.